# Allowing LZMA page compression through plugin (without recompiling) on Windows

Tags: windows, mariadb, lzma

MariaDB supports [page compression algorithms](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-page-compression/) through [plugins](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/compression-plugins/):

Adding LZMA would amount to something like:

```
INSTALL SONAME 'provider_lzma';
```

Where can I find these plugins (DLLs) for Windows? They are not distributed with the MariaDB binaries for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the documentation, the compression plugins are available depending on the platform.
This means the plugins are only created if the corresponding compression library is available by default on the respective platform.

In order to create all plugins, all external libraries would have to be statically linked, which would bring some disadvantages (memory consumption, rebuild on library update, package size, ..)

So the only solution would be to install liblzma libraries and headers and rebuild MariaDB Server.

From the MariaDB windows builder log file (10.8 build):

```
-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * Git
 * LibXml2
 * PMEM
 * CURL
 * Boost (required version >= 1.40.0)
   Required for the OQGraph storage engine
 * BZip2
 * LZ4 (required version >= 1.6)
 * LibLZMA
 * LZO
 * Snappy
```

Comment: Whole point of a plugin is to bypass recompilation. Hence although not an answer to the question, still informative: +1.

Comment: I agree, but often this is only possible if you link statically against external libraries. Beside the facts I already mentioned in my answer static linking often doesn't work due to GPL restrictions or license restriction of the external library.